Spacially Separated Reference Frames in SR
I'm not sure I understand the Lorentz transformation so well:
Let's consider event $\text{A}$ to be Allan's existence at his space-time origin in his rest frame. So $\text{A} = (0,0)$. It represents Allan standing where he is at a time he perceives to be $0$.
If we transform to Bill's rest frame, $\text{A}' = (0,0)$, since the Lorentz transformation is linear, so $0$ always goes to $0$. However, in Bill's rest frame, this corresponds to where he is standing at some time in origin.
Clearly, Bill does not think that Allan is standing on top of him, so what happened?
Must all reference frames be transformed between sharing an origin? If so, how can we transform between rest frames of things that never are at the same place in space-time?
If not, how do you account for the fact that $\text{A} = (0,0)$ and $\text{A}' = (0,0)$ clearly mean very different things to their frame's owners?

Linear does not mean that 0 will be 0. What makes you think that? Linear means 0 will be $a×0 + b$;  $b$ doesn’t have to be 0.

@HassanIbra well, I meant it was a linear transformation. Linear transformations do map 0->0.

Poincaré transformations can shift the origin. Lorentz transformations, by definition, do not.

The questions you ask could also be directed to Euclidean transformations and to Galilean transformations. It’s not exclusively a special relativity issue.

I like @Ghoster's response -- I think the resolution to my confusion is that $A' \ne \Lambda A$, generally speaking. Instead, $A' = T A$, where $T$ is some transformation in the Poincare Group consisting often of boosts but also others, to actually transform between the frames.

Reference Frame is different from Coordinate System. RFs differ by state of motion (linear or rotational), while CSs describe different ways of labeling points within a given RF.
In one RF, you can have a point $(x,y) = (1, 0)$, or you can slide the x-axis and express the same point as $(x',y') = (-1, 0)$, or rotate the CS and get $(x'',y'') = (1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2)$.  These are all just labels, but they do not change any of the spatial relationships or trajectories of any point or object.
Changing RF, in contrast, means changing the observer's state of motion. In Galileian transformations (used in Newtonian physics, and which provide good predictions for 98% of things in practical life) you boost to a new reference frame by subtracting a velocity $\vec v$ from every velocity being considered.  For example, changing from the RF of a man in the ground to the RF of a man in a train going by, one would subtract the velocity of the train from all object velocities. E.g. the train man's velocity boosts from $\vec v$ to 0, and the ground man's velocity boosts from 0 to $-\vec v$. But in this new RF, you are still free to choose a CS.  You can decide that the two men have coordinates $(x, y, z)$ and $(\xi, \eta, \zeta)$, with $x$ and $\xi$ aligned and pointed in the same direction. Furthermore, we can decide when the two men pass each other, they both call their position zero, i.e. $x=0$ and $\xi=0$.  These types of assumptions simplify the math considerably to better illustrate the physical concepts. But the train man could just as easily decide his $\xi=0$ is 100 miles down the track, so he is at $\xi=-100$ when $x=0$.  These choices have nothing to do with the RF, and are simply a matter of the CS choice.
Notice I have not said anything about Special Relativity.  It is important to gain a strong understanding of how to describe motion and physical terminology in a Newtonian context, before adding Relativity into the mix. Your question on the $A$ and $A'$ positions is a question about CSs and RFs, not Relativity.
The difference with Relativity is that it we want to boost from one RF to another, instead of simply subtracting a velocity vector $\vec v$, we must use the Lorenz Transformation Equations to boost between two RFs in different states of motion.
